# sql query and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

i don't sure this to possible i don't have idea this my tables : tbchecked

```
[id] [name] [status]

001   john     present
001   john     present
001   john     absent
001   john     absent
001   john     leave
001   john     present
001   john     present
002   ace      present
002   ace      absent
002   ace      leave
```

...

it is possible? to output in gridview1 how to query?
1-7 is not in week i want count 1 to xxx

```
[id] [name] [1]      [2]      [3]     [4]             [5]            [6]      [7]

001   john  present  present  absent  absent         leave          present  present
002   ace   present  absent   leave   ...
```

Comment: Pivoting and dynamic query. Why you want 7 columns? How they are projected.

Comment: Do you have a primary key?A table is inherently unordered.

Comment: This question is very very hard to understand! Please explain more.

Comment: 7 = days of week I guess

Comment: @user3471353 consider adding a 4th column identifying the column (1-7)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array). It's so much simpler, more flexible, and more scalable. Note also that you appear to be lacking a PRIMARY KEY. This is a fatal omission.

Comment: @Strawberry is correct, if u want to display same on front-end then try to pu you logic there,you can bind rows as columns & partition to next row when value of id is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(  
ID INT,  
STATUS VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE  
VALUES  (1, 'present'),
        (1, 'present'),
        (1, 'absent'),
        (1, 'absent'),
        (1, 'leave'),
        (1, 'present'),
        (1, 'present'),
        (2, 'present'),
        (2, 'absent'),
        (2, 'leave')


SELECT T1.ID,  
        STUFF(  
        (  
        SELECT ',' + T2.STATUS  
        FROM @TABLE T2  
        WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID  
        FOR XML PATH ('')  
        ),1,1,'')  
FROM @TABLE T1  
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

Otherwise you can use a cursor to perform a cycle [Declare Cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms180169.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only seven rows for an ID then this may be useful. 
If ID is of any random count  then you have to go 
for dynamic sql or a procedure if possible.

```
select ID,

SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','2'),',','-1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','3'),',','-1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','4'),',','-1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','5'),',','-1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','6'),',','-1'),

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,',','7'),',','-1')

 from
(

SELECT  ID, group_concat(status) as status  

FROM TABLE T

GROUP BY ID

) A
```